# Incremental Gaussian Process Regression

Tags: regression, covariance, gaussian-process, linear-algebra, online-algorithms

I want to implement an incremental gaussian process regression using a sliding window over the data points which arrives one by one through a stream.

Let $d$ denote the dimensionality of the input space. So, every data point $x_i$ has $d$ number of elements.

Let $n$ be the size of the sliding window.

In order to make predictions, I need to compute the inverse of the gram matrix $K$, where $K_{ij} = k(x_i, x_j)$ and k is the squared exponential kernel.

In order to avoid K getting bigger with every new data point, I thought I could remove the oldest data point before adding new points and this way I prevent the the gram from growing. For example, let $K = \phi(X)^{T}\Sigma\phi(X)$ where $\Sigma$ is the covariance of the weights and $\phi$ is the implicit mapping function implied by the squared exponential kernel.

Now let $X=[x_{t-n+1}|x_{t-n+2}|...|x_{t}$] and $X_{new}=[x_{t-n+2}|...|x_{t}|x_{t+1}]$ where $x$'s are $d$ by $1$ column matrices.

I need an effective way to find the $K_{new}^{-1}$ potentially using $K$. This doesn't look like the inverse of a rank-1 updated matrix problem that can be efficiently dealt with Sherman-Morrison formula.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There have been several recursive algorithms for doing this. You should take a look at kernel recursive least squares (KRLS) algorithm, and related online GP algorithms.

- Van Vaerenbergh, S., Santamaria, I., Liu, W., and Principe, J. C. (2010). [Fixed-budget kernel recursive least-squares](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/icassp.2010.5495350). In Acoustics Speech and Signal Processing (ICASSP), 2010 IEEE International Conference on, pages 1882-1885. IEEE.
- Lazaro-Gredilla, M., Van Vaerenbergh, S., and Santamaria, I. (2011). [A Bayesian approach to tracking with kernel recursive least-squares](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/mlsp.2011.6064585). In Machine Learning for Signal Processing (MLSP), 2011 IEEE International Workshop on, pages 1-6. IEEE.
- Perez-Cruz, F., Van Vaerenbergh, S., Murillo-Fuentes, J. J., Lazaro-Gredilla, M., and Santamaria, I. (2013). [Gaussian processes for nonlinear signal processing: An overview of recent advances](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/msp.2013.2250352). IEEE Signal Processing Magazine, 30(4):40-50.

Answer (score -1):

Stepwise estimation of GP models is well studied in literature. 
The underlying idea is instead of conditioning on all new observations you want to predict, condition on the one-step ahead point and do this repeatedly. This becomes somehow close to kalman filtering.

Comment: This answer would be improved if it cited a book, article, or other scholarly publication.